SocketException (SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 192.168.1.149, port = 38772)
Im trying to handle error on mqtt protocol connection. But im getting that error.
Here is my func to attempt re-connection
Future<bool> _attemptConnectionWithTimeout() async {
    final completer = Completer<bool>();
    Timer? timer;

    // Jika koneksi sukses, selesaikan dengan true
    Future(() async {
      try {
        await _client!
            .connect(); // error here (SocketException: Connection refused)
        if (_client!.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
          completer.complete(true);
        } else {
          completer.complete(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        completer.complete(false);
      }
    });

    // Jika melebihi timeout 10 detik, selesaikan dengan false
    timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      completer.complete(false);
    });

    final result = await completer.future;
    timer?.cancel();
    return result;
  }


The error implies nothing is listening on the port
